# A-Frame Physics System : custom physics materials

Tags: virtual-reality, aframe, cannon.js

I have created a scene in A-Frame using 'A-Frame Physics System' (https://github.com/donmccurdy/aframe-physics-system) :

```
<!DOCTYPE>
<html>
<head>

<script src="aframe.min.js"></script>
<script src="aframe-extras.min.js"></script>
<script src="aframe-physics-system-master/dist/aframe-physics-system.min.js"></script>
</head>

  <a-scene id="myscene" physics>
    <!--CAMERA-->
    <a-entity camera="userHeight: 1.6" look-controls></a-entity>

    <!--BALL1-->
    <a-sphere color="red" radius="0.3" position="5 5 5" dynamic-body></a-sphere>

    <!--BALL2-->
    <a-sphere color="green" radius="0.3" position="6 5 5" dynamic-body></a-sphere>

    <!--GROUND-->
    <a-plane id="ground" height="200" width="200" rotation="-90 0 0" position="0 0 0" metalness="0" roughness="1" static-body></a-plane>

  </a-scene>
</body>
</html>
```

The scene consist of two spheres and one plane. I want one ball to bounce more than other when it hits plane. I got to know from the documentation that we can change properties like friction and restitution for whole scene using :

```
<a-scene physics="friction: 0.1; restitution: 0.5">
    <!-- ... -->
</a-scene>
```

But I want different friction and restitution values for different spheres. Please let me know if it is possible in A-Frame. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the [physics component documentation](https://github.com/donmccurdy/aframe-physics-system): specifying different collision behaviors for different objects is available through the CANNON.js JavaScript API.

For custom behaviour, You need to dig in to the [Cannon.js documentation](http://www.cannonjs.org/) and find Your desired methods and classes. Nonetheless, implementing custom materials goes like this:

- Cannon physics are computed/made in their own Cannon.world
- Cannon Objecs have thier own materials
- Cannon.ContactMaterial defines the physics, when those objects collide/interact with each other. It needs to be added to the Cannon.world as it is responsible for the physics.

With these, You can start by doing the following:

- Get the CANNON.world reference: 
  `var world = $('a-scene')[0].systems.physics.world;`
- create two custom materials like this: 
  `var firstMaterial = new CANNON.Material("firstMaterial");
  var secondMaterial = new CANNON.Material("secondMaterial");`
- apply the materials to the a-frame objects:
  `$('#cannon')[0].body.material=firstMaterial;
  $('floor')[0].body.material=secondMaterial;`
- create a contact material and add it to the world 
  `var secondCM = new CANNON.ContactMaterial(firstMaterial,secondMaterial,
  [restitution = 2]); 
  world.addContactMaterial(secondCM);`

[Here](https://jsfiddle.net/2hjqm2hq/) You can find a working fiddle.

Comment: Thanks Adam for the reply. I have created custom materials and also contact material. But when  I apply it to sphere and ground, it gives following warning : **Unknown property 10 for component/system `material`.* I apply the material as follows : <a-sphere color="red" radius="0.3" position="5 5 5" dynamic-body material="ball1material"></a-sphere>

Comment: @KK1993 hi, i've edited my anwser so You could easily follow my steps to achieve what You initially wanted

Comment: @KK1993 glad i could help :)